# nuxt vue-router is working before api call but not working in api response body

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I am using vform for submitting a form and using @nuxtjs/router package for routing. Now I need to navigate to another page from vuex action. what I am doing is sending $router and the form from my component in vuex action. Navigation is working fine when I use router.push() outside of response body but inside axios response body the router is not working and it is showing some error.

Sending form and router from Component:

```
<form @submit.prevent="createProperty({form: form, router: $router})">
...
</form>
```

and in vuex action:

```
    createProperty({commit, dispatch}, payload){
        
        const {form, router} = payload;
        console.log("outside", router); // Here the router is ok

        form.post('/property').then(res => {
          
            commit("SET_PROPERTY", res.data.data);
            console.log("inside", router);  // But Here Router is not ok
            router.push({name: 'partner.property.basic-info', query: { slug: res.data.data.slug }});
    
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    
    },
```

It throws the following error

[image: It shows the following]

Comment: You cannot route the user to the next route because you have an error in the `SET_PROPERTY`

The error related to the `property` value in the `state`, check the default value, should be empty array for `push` function.

Comment: What is the code of `SET_PROPERTY`?

Comment: Thanks. It solved the problem. The Problem was in SET_PROPERTY. This simple problem waste lots of my time.